# Подключение к БД с помощью аутенфикации Windows (python)

Tags: python, sql

Всем привет, мне нужно подключиться к БД с помощью аутентификации на Windows.

На просторах интернета массу решений с использованием имени пользователя, пароля и т. д. Но у меня нет таких данных.

Comment: А какая БД? MS SQL?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы здесь например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо